# How to I force a word to move to the end of the line?

Tags: formatting, line-breaking, typography, hyphenation, books

How do I force my document to pull selected words to the end of each line (and to hyphenate them as well, if needed)?

I have an old document. I know the page size and I think I've found the corresponding modern font for the original typeface. However, I don't know the exact margins and some other details. Is there a way for me to designate words as being at the end of the line, and then having the rest of the words justify themselves?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[paperwidth=25.7cm, paperheight=40.6cm,bindingoffset=0in,left=1.2in,right=0.5in,
    top=0.9in,bottom=1in,footskip=.25in]{geometry}


    \usepackage{lettrine}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
        \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={Historical}}
        \setmainfont[Ligatures={Common,Rare},Scale=1.9]{Adobe Caslon Pro}

    \newcommand{\prelude}[1]{\textsuperscript{\emph{#1.}\quad}}  


    \begin{document}
       \noindent deſires, may reſt there. Purge our hearts from envy, hatred, and malice; 
       that we may never ſuffer the ſun to go down upon our wrath ; but may always go to 
       our reſt in peace, charity, and good-will, with a conſcience void of offence
       towards thee and towards men: That ſo we may be preſerved pure and blameleſs,
       unto the coming of our Lord and Saviour Jeſus Chriſt. \textit{Amen.}
       \lettrine[ante={\prelude{The Interceſſion}}, loversize=0.2]{A}{ND} 
        accept, O Lord, our interceſſions for all mankind. Let the light of
        thy Goſpel ſhine upon all nations; and may as many as have received it,
        live as becomes it. Be gracious unto thy Church; and grant that every member
        of the fame, in his vocation and miniſtry, may ſerve thee faithfully. Bleſs
        all in authority over us; and ſo rule their hearts and ſtrengthen their hands,
        that they may puniſh wickedneſs and vice, and maintain thy true religion and virtue.
        Send down thy bleſſings temporal and ſpiritual, upon all our relations, friends,
        and neighbours. Reward all who have done us good, and pardon all thoſe who have
        done or wiſh us evil, and give them repentance and better minds. Be merciful to
        all who are in any trouble; and do thou, the God of pity, adminiſter to them 
        according to their ſeveral neceſſities, for his ſake who went about doing good,
        thy Son our Saviour Jeſus Chriſt. \textit{Amen.}

       \lettrine[ante={\prelude{The Thanksgiving}}, loversize=0.1]{T}{O} 
          our prayers, O Lord, we join our unfeigned thanks for all the 
          mercies; for our being, our reaſon, and all other endowments and faculties of ſoul
          and body; for our health, friends, food, and raiment, and all the other comforts and
          conveniences of life. Above all we adore thy mercy in ſending thy only Son into the
          world to redeem us from ſin and eternal death, and in giving us the knowledge and           
          ſenſe of our duty towards thee. We bleſs thee for thy patience with us, notwithſtanding
          our many and great provocations; for all the directions, aſſiſtances, and comforts of thy
          Holy Spirit; for thy continual care and watchful providence over us through the whole
          courſe of our lives; and particularly for the mercies and benefits of the paſt day:
          Beſecching thee to continue theſe thy bleſſings to us; and to give is grace to ſhow
          our thankfulneſs in a ſincere obedience to his laws through whoſe merits and
          interceſſion we received them all, thy Son our Saviour Jeſus Chriſt. \textit{Amen.}

       \lettrine[ante={\prelude{Prayer for God's pro-\\tection through the night
       following.}}, loversize=0.1]{I}{N} particular we beſeech thee to continue thy
gracious protection to us this night. Defend us from all dangers and miſchiefs, and from
the fear of them; that we may enjoy ſuch refreſhing ſleep as may lit us for the 
duties of the following day. Make us ever mindful of the time when we ſhall lie
 down in the duſt; and grant us grace always to live in fuch a ſtate, that we may
 never be afraid to die: So that living and dying we may be thine, through the 
 merits and ſatisfaction of thy Son Chriſt Jeſus, in whoſe Name we offer up theſe 
 imperfect prayers. Amen.
       THE grace of our Lord Jeſus Chriſt, and the love of God, and the fellowſhip of
       the Holy Ghoſt, be with us all evermore. \textit{Amen.}

       \begin{center}
       \textpilcrow \textit{ On Sundays and on other days, when it may be convenient,
it will be proper to begin with a\\Chapter, or part of a Chapter, from the New Teſtament}
       \end{center}

    \end{document}
```

Here's a screencap of the original (left) and the output (right).

[image: Screencap]

Also how would I go about forcing 'protection' to become 'pro-tection' (with a return) in `\lettrine[ante={\prelude{Prayer for God's pro-\\tection through the night
           following.}}, loversize=0.1]{I}{N}` ?

Comment: Mmm I read three interesting and not easy questions yours today (actually the two firsts yesterday). I have not a solution for them but I see that you need to take more control of the text that one the most of packages commonly gives you.

So perhaps you need to take a look at the TeX commands, that's my suggestion. Create facsimilar texts is not an easy task, you have good eye, but you need to learn LaTeX and TeX depeer for that.

Comment: What packages would you recommend?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm not sure to completely understand your requests, but what about something like this?

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[paperwidth=25.7cm, paperheight=40.6cm,bindingoffset=0in,left=1.2in,right=0.5in,
    top=0.9in,bottom=1in,footskip=.25in]{geometry}

    \usepackage{graphicx}

    \usepackage{lettrine}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
        \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={Historical}}
        \setmainfont[Ligatures={Common,Rare},Scale=1.9]{Adobe Caslon Pro}

    \newcommand{\prelude}[1]{%
      \raisebox{0.5\baselineskip}{\parbox[t]{4.5cm}{\scriptsize\hspace{1em}\emph{#1.}}\quad}}

    \linespread{1.75}\selectfont
    \setlength{\parskip}{10pt}


    \begin{document}
       \noindent deſires, may reſt there. Purge our hearts from envy, hatred, and malice;
       that we may never ſuffer the ſun to go down upon our wrath ; but may always go to
       our reſt in peace, charity, and good-will, with a conſcience void of offence
       towards thee and towards men: That ſo we may be preſerved pure and blameleſs,
       unto the coming of our Lord and Saviour Jeſus Chriſt. \textit{Amen.}
       \lettrine[ante={\prelude{The Interceſſion}}]{A}{ND}
        accept, O Lord, our interceſſions for all mankind. Let the light of
        thy Goſpel ſhine upon all nations; and may as many as have received it,
        live as becomes it. Be gracious unto thy Church; and grant that every member
        of the fame, in his vocation and miniſtry, may ſerve thee faithfully. Bleſs
        all in authority over us; and ſo rule their hearts and ſtrengthen their hands,
        that they may puniſh wickedneſs and vice, and maintain thy true religion and virtue.
        Send down thy bleſſings temporal and ſpiritual, upon all our relations, friends,
        and neighbours. Reward all who have done us good, and pardon all thoſe who have
        done or wiſh us evil, and give them repentance and better minds. Be merciful to
        all who are in any trouble; and do thou, the God of pity, adminiſter to them
        according to their ſeveral neceſſities, for his ſake who went about doing good,
        thy Son our Saviour Jeſus Chriſt. \textit{Amen.}

       \lettrine[ante={\prelude{The Thanksgiving}}]{T}{O}
          our prayers, O Lord, we join our unfeigned thanks for all the
          mercies; for our being, our reaſon, and all other endowments and faculties of ſoul
          and body; for our health, friends, food, and raiment, and all the other comforts and
          conveniences of life. Above all we adore thy mercy in ſending thy only Son into the
          world to redeem us from ſin and eternal death, and in giving us the knowledge and
          ſenſe of our duty towards thee. We bleſs thee for thy patience with us, notwithſtanding
          our many and great provocations; for all the directions, aſſiſtances, and comforts of thy
          Holy Spirit; for thy continual care and watchful providence over us through the whole
          courſe of our lives; and particularly for the mercies and benefits of the paſt day:
          Beſecching thee to continue theſe thy bleſſings to us; and to give is grace to ſhow
          our thankfulneſs in a ſincere obedience to his laws through whoſe merits and
          interceſſion we received them all, thy Son our Saviour Jeſus Chriſt. \textit{Amen.}

       \lettrine[ante={\prelude{Prayer for God's protection through the night
       following}}]{I}{N} particular we beſeech thee to continue thy
gracious protection to us this night. Defend us from all dangers and miſchiefs, and from
the fear of them; that we may enjoy ſuch refreſhing ſleep as may lit us for the
duties of the following day. Make us ever mindful of the time when we ſhall lie
 down in the duſt; and grant us grace always to live in fuch a ſtate, that we may
 never be afraid to die: So that living and dying we may be thine, through the
 merits and ſatisfaction of thy Son Chriſt Jeſus, in whoſe Name we offer up theſe
 imperfect prayers. Amen.
       THE grace of our Lord Jeſus Chriſt, and the love of God, and the fellowſhip of
       the Holy Ghoſt, be with us all evermore. \textit{Amen.}

       \begin{center}
       \textpilcrow \textit{ On Sundays and on other days, when it may be convenient,
it will be proper to begin with a\\Chapter, or part of a Chapter, from the New Teſtament}
       \end{center}

    \end{document}
```

What I've changed:

- I've removed all `loversize`s from your `\lettrine`s
- I've increased the spacing between lines through

  ```
  \linespread{1.75}\selectfont
  ```
- I've increased the spacing between paragraphs through

  ```
  \setlength{\parskip}{10pt}
  ```
- I've completely changed your `\prelude` command inserting it in a `\parbox` so words are hyphenated automatically and all of them have the same size.

---

### EDIT

A new version, with a manual break inside `\prelude` (to show how it works) and some improvements (note the third `\lettrine`...)

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[paperwidth=25.7cm, paperheight=40.6cm,bindingoffset=0in,left=1.2in,right=0.5in,
    top=0.9in,bottom=1in,footskip=.25in]{geometry}

    \usepackage{graphicx}

    \usepackage{lettrine}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
        \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={Historical}}
        \setmainfont[Ligatures={Common,Rare},Scale=1.9]{Adobe Caslon Pro}

    \newcommand{\prelude}[1]{%
      \raisebox{0.5\baselineskip}{\parbox[t]{4.5cm}{\scriptsize\hspace{1em}\emph{#1.}}\quad}}

 %  \linespread{1.75}\selectfont
    \setlength{\parskip}{10pt}

    \renewcommand*{\DefaultLraise}{-0.4}
    \renewcommand*{\DefaultLoversize}{0.2}


    \begin{document}
       \noindent deſires, may reſt there. Purge our hearts from envy, hatred, and malice;
       that we may never ſuffer the ſun to go down upon our wrath ; but may always go to
       our reſt in peace, charity, and good-will, with a conſcience void of offence
       towards thee and towards men: That ſo we may be preſerved pure and blameleſs,
       unto the coming of our Lord and Saviour Jeſus Chriſt. \textit{Amen.}
       \lettrine[ante={\prelude{The Interceſſion}}]{A}{ND}
        accept, O Lord, our interceſſions for all mankind. Let the light of
        thy Goſpel ſhine upon all nations; and may as many as have received it,
        live as becomes it. Be gracious unto thy Church; and grant that every member
        of the fame, in his vocation and miniſtry, may ſerve thee faithfully. Bleſs
        all in authority over us; and ſo rule their hearts and ſtrengthen their hands,
        that they may puniſh wickedneſs and vice, and maintain thy true religion and virtue.
        Send down thy bleſſings temporal and ſpiritual, upon all our relations, friends,
        and neighbours. Reward all who have done us good, and pardon all thoſe who have
        done or wiſh us evil, and give them repentance and better minds. Be merciful to
        all who are in any trouble; and do thou, the God of pity, adminiſter to them
        according to their ſeveral neceſſities, for his ſake who went about doing good,
        thy Son our Saviour Jeſus Chriſt. \textit{Amen.}

       \lettrine[ante={\prelude{The Thanksgiving}}]{T}{O}
          our prayers, O Lord, we join our unfeigned thanks for all the
          mercies; for our being, our reaſon, and all other endowments and faculties of ſoul
          and body; for our health, friends, food, and raiment, and all the other comforts and
          conveniences of life. Above all we adore thy mercy in ſending thy only Son into the
          world to redeem us from ſin and eternal death, and in giving us the knowledge and
          ſenſe of our duty towards thee. We bleſs thee for thy patience with us, notwithſtanding
          our many and great provocations; for all the directions, aſſiſtances, and comforts of thy
          Holy Spirit; for thy continual care and watchful providence over us through the whole
          courſe of our lives; and particularly for the mercies and benefits of the paſt day:
          Beſecching thee to continue theſe thy bleſſings to us; and to give is grace to ſhow
          our thankfulneſs in a ſincere obedience to his laws through whoſe merits and
          interceſſion we received them all, thy Son our Saviour Jeſus Chriſt. \textit{Amen.}

       \lettrine[ante={\prelude{Prayer for God's pro-\linebreak tection through the night
       following}},lines=3,loversize=-0.2,lraise=0.1,slope=-25pt]{I}{N} particular we beſeech thee to continue thy
gracious protection to us this night. Defend us from all dangers and miſchiefs, and from
the fear of them; that we may enjoy ſuch refreſhing ſleep as may lit us for the
duties of the following day. Make us ever mindful of the time when we ſhall lie
 down in the duſt; and grant us grace always to live in fuch a ſtate, that we may
 never be afraid to die: So that living and dying we may be thine, through the
 merits and ſatisfaction of thy Son Chriſt Jeſus, in whoſe Name we offer up theſe
 imperfect prayers. Amen.
       THE grace of our Lord Jeſus Chriſt, and the love of God, and the fellowſhip of
       the Holy Ghoſt, be with us all evermore. \textit{Amen.}

       \begin{center}
       \textpilcrow \textit{ On Sundays and on other days, when it may be convenient,
it will be proper to begin with a\\Chapter, or part of a Chapter, from the New Teſtament}
       \end{center}

    \end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yes, spot on--thank you--except for that I'm looking to insert the equivalent of InDesign's forced line break after the words that fall at the end of each line.

Comment: @PhilVollman If you want to force a line break use `\prelude{Prayer for God's pro-\linebreak tection...`